# List item with two spans align left and right

Tags: html, css, alignment

I currently have a list that looks like this.

```
<li><a href="#"><span class="short">SHORT</span> <span class="long">LONG</span></a></li>
```

I would like to have the short span aligned to the right and the long span to be aligned to the left.

I currently have the list at a width of 350px and was using this for the long span.

```
.long {

   width: 300px;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0px;
}
```

Can't seem to find a way to get the short span to align to the right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using `float`?

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 500px;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;             
}

.long {
    width: 300px;
    float:left;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.short {
    width: 200px;
    float:right;
    background-color: green;   
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Ended up adding, text-align:right; to the .short span and after adding the clearfix, it worked perfectly. Thanks